# Is the ciphertext given by encrypting a file with CipherInputStream the same length then the file itself

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt files using CipherInputStream. I want to add a progress bar during the encryption.

The problem is that the ciphertext doesn't seem to be the same length as the file. It means I cannot know when cipherInputStream.read(bytes) is going to return -1.

How to know that in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the mode of operation, so the stream itself won't tell you this. Generally however, when using a symmetric cipher, the size of the ciphertext should only be one block more at the maximum. So in general for long ciphertext, only displaying the full 100% may be an issue (but then you're done, right?).

For CTR mode, there is no overhead.

For ECB or CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding ([`"PKCS5Padding"` in Java](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172)) the overhead is maximum one full block and at minimal one byte. You can calculate the amount of padding by using:

```
int n = cipher.getBlockSize();
int pad = n - plaintextSize % n;
```

For GCM mode the authentication tag is included, which defaults to 16 bytes.

For all modes except ECB, the IV may be prefixed to the ciphertext.

---

Great, that's my direct answer. Let's invalidate it.

**Don't use `CipherInputStream` to encrypt**. Use `CipherOutputStream` to encrypt instead. That way you know exactly when everything ends: when the last block of the original input stream has been encrypted. After all, you don't need encrypted ciphertext in your application, right? See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60121450/589259) about encoding / decoding.